# Move from sylpheed to Thunderbird easily

Tags: email, thunderbird

I've been using Sylpheed, but it is very bug-full and hard to use, so I'm trying to move all 8gb of my mails to Thunderbird (have been losing business emails left right and center, deletes entire folders, fails to load emails etc).  I tried Export mail data and ImportExport tools, but no luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any update? To go the other way around, you can use https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46001/101324 To go from sylpheed to Thunderbird, according to https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2011/06/msg01915.html , "Sylpheed can export an MH file, and T'bird can read it after indexing."

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do it with [formail](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/formail.htm) and the [ImportExortTools](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) plug-in, but I haven't found it yet…